# Flutter Web: Prerender ListView

Tags: flutter, flutter-web

I'm using Flutter Web and I want to prerender a ListView instead of building widgets as the user scrolls, you can see this behaviour on my test site: https://auties00.github.io
This causes performance issues especially on mobile, please ignore the List as I'm testing out a few methodologies to scroll to an index of a ListView.
Source Code:

```
class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  final ScrollController _controller = ScrollController();
  final List<GlobalKey> _keys = [];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    reset();
    _keys.clear();
    var size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    ScreenUtil.init(context, width: size.width, height: size.height);

    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
          child: NotificationListener<OverscrollIndicatorNotification>(
              onNotification: (e) {
                e.disallowGlow();
                return false;
              },

              child: _buildBody()
          )
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _buildBody(){
    return LayoutBuilder(
      builder: (context, constraints) {
        _initWebListeners(constraints);
        return ListView.builder(
          controller: _controller,
          physics: const AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics(),
          itemBuilder: (var context, var index) {
            switch (index) {
              case 0: return WebNavigationBar(
                  key: GlobalKey()..addKeyToList(_keys),
                  keys: _keys
              );

              case 1:return WebAnnouncement(
                key: GlobalKey()..addKeyToList(_keys),
              );

              case 2: return WebPlayer(
                  key: GlobalKey()..addKeyToList(_keys),
                  link: 'https://i.imgur.com/VPTYKX2.mp4'
              );

              case 4: return WebIntroduction(
                key: GlobalKey()..addKeyToList(_keys),
              );

              case 6: return WebFeatures(
                key: GlobalKey()..addKeyToList(_keys),
              );

              case 8: return WebPricing(
                key: GlobalKey()..addKeyToList(_keys),
              );

              case 9: return WebFooter(
                key: GlobalKey()..addKeyToList(_keys),
              );
            }

            return WebDivider();
          },
          itemCount: 10
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I don't get what do you mean by pre-render? I guess you can use Listview instead of Listview.builder.

Comment: @ZeeshanHussain With my current implementation widgets are built as the user scrolls, I want to build all of them at the beginning

Comment: You can use the ListView constructor instead of Listview.builder

Comment: @ZeeshanHussain That's not how it works

Comment: does not listview builds the entire list once? Sorry, if I am wrong.

Comment: @ZeeshanHussain That's what flutter says, but it's not the case for the web. I added a print message in the build method of my widgets and I can clearly see that even with the ListView constructor they are still built as the user scrolls

Comment: does anybody found solution to this ?

Answer (score -1):

Try putting all the widgets in a column.
Then place the column as one child in the listview.
It improves performance slightly.